# Cannot get text using text() in XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, testng, service-locator

Here is part of html code:

```html
<td class="audit-context-break-word text-left" nowrap="nowrap">
<b class="ng-binding">PONumber</b></td>
<td class="audit-context-break-word text-left ng-binding">20202022  02_001  </td>
```

I need to get only text inside (expected value: 20202022  02_001) I tried following variants:

```
By.xpath("/descendant::*[.='PONumber']/../descendant::*[@class=\"audit-context-break-word text-left ng-binding\"]/text()")
By.xpath("/descendant::*[.='PONumber']/../following::text()[1]")
```

The issue is that in FirePath selected text is found, but not in test. It is failed due to timeout exception, because element is not found

What is the reason of the failure?

Comment: Does it have to be XPath?

Comment: Not necessarily XPath, any other ways are also acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling` to write the Xpath.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[b[contains(text(),'PONumber')]]/following-sibling::td"));
        String text = element.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
```

1. I'm identifying appropriate web element on the webpage and saving it in web element.
2. Using `getText()` method to obtain text from that web Element and saving it in string
3. Print that string `text`

Comment: thanks! tried your option, but still empty string is returned

Comment: if so @Yuliya you can you the following xpath

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'20202022 02_001')]")).getText();

or

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[b[contains(text(),'PONumber')]]/following-sibling::td[contains(text(),'20202022 02_001')]"));

Comment: finally resolved:  
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[b = 'PONumber']/following-sibling::td"));
        String text = element.getAttribute("textContent");
        String ponumber = StringUtils.trim(text);
        return ponumber;

Answer (score 1):

[`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) is something you should use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[b = 'PONumber']/following-sibling::td")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot evaluate text() function of xpath. you can run javascript and can get result. run following javascript in your program:

```
document.evaluate("//span[@class='tableNode']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
```

if you use Python or Java, i can present

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where an element was visible but tests wouldn't pass on isTextPresent. When I checked the source code, it was

2-1180 \&\nbsp CITY 2

, whereas the test was looking for "2-1180 CITY 2". Check if you have a similar problem too. Let us know what works for you, would be interested in knowing.

Note: do not downvote, just trying to help.